# Difference between "Within" estimator for $Y_\textit{diff} = Y_{t_i} - Y_{t_{i - 1}}$ vs "First Difference" estimator for $Y_{t_i}$

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, estimators, difference-in-difference

I am using a diff-in-diff strategy and have a few question.

I am not getting equivalent coefficient estimates for the two following regressions on panel data:

1. a panel regression with a fixed effects estimator (i.e. the "within" estimator e.g. in R plm package, model = "within") on a pre-differenced variable: $Y_\textit{diff} = Y_{t_i} - Y_{t_{i - 1}}$.
2. a panel regression with a "first difference" estimator (e.g. in R plm package, model = "fd") on the  untransformed variable: $Y_{t_i}$.

The estimate for the diff-in-diff term for the model estimated using "first difference" is quite different from the estimate for the diff-in-diff term when estimated using the "within" estimator.

**Some background**

In case it may be relevant, here is a high-level description of the current panel:

1. I am currently using Panel Data that spans 27 years at the county/district level
2. Counties are clustered into groups for the entire window (non-random assignment, e.g. urban/rural)

   3. It is a repeated measures design. Every few years, treatment occurs at the group level by random assignment - where all entites in a particular group either receive Treatment-X or Treatment-Y.
   4. While entities are not randomly assigned to groups, treatment is randomly assigned.
   5. Each of the two groups undergoes 2 exposures to Treatment-X and 2 exposures to Treatment-Y over the course of the entire time window, resulting in 4 pre-post measures.

I cannot quite understand why the estimates are not identical:

**My Question**

1. Why might this be happening?
2. What is the difference between the "First Diff" model on Y vs Within model on Chg in Y (i.e Y diff)
3. What is the correct use of the "model" parameter and, crucially:
   when should model = "fd" be used vs model = "within" (especially, when dealing with "change variables" **$Y_\textit{diff}$ on the LHS)
4. In your opinion, which of the two would be most appropriate here and how would you decide?
5. Why are "twoway" fixed effects no longer allowed when using model = "fd"